# Как создать Scala проект со сборкой в IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, scala

Все здравствуйте! Я впервые решил попробовать для себя Gradle со Scala. Не могу разобраться, как создать проект на Scala с системой сборки Gradle. В "New Project", когда я выбираю Scala, не отображается система сборки Gradle (в поддержке написали, что это нормально, такого и не должно быть). Мне сказали, что нужно создать build.gradle, тогда идея сама подтянет Gradle. Такое было, однако, во время загрузки данной системы сборки в проекте, созданного в "New Project" -> "Scala", система сборки - "IntelliJ IDEA" появляется ошибка в консоли:

```
Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\��������\AppData\Local\Temp\wrapper_init11.gradle' (C:\Users\��������\.gradle\caches\8.0\scripts\2tfq55txqc8kphqp69se8ohu3).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64

* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Можете кратко мне объяснить, как правильно создавать такой проект?

Comment: В пути есть каталог с вашим именем пользователя, написанным не латиницей. Это может быть проблемой для некоторых скриптов сборки.